# jQuery slideToggle - when div is toggled it pushes content out of viewable area (IE)

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer, slider

This is an annoying ocurrance in IE when I use the jQuery slideToggle effect. Without the div being open, page looks normal. The minute I toggle the div open, it extends past the current content, overtop of the footer, and out of the viewable browser area (Even after scrolling all the way down).

This feature seems to work just fine in firefox. Do I need an additional hack or CSS to make it work in IE8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this often happens when you forget to close a tag. Is your html valid?